# Why negative bars of a bar chart not displayed in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Lately I am working on a shiny project and want to make a bar chart with renderplotly(ggplot object). Why negative bars of a bar chart not displayed in shiny app? The negative part is not displayed. Any reason for it? My code is irrelevant but it is

My codes:

```
g_dpnl_ts <- ggplot(aes(x=time), data=dpnl_ts) +
    geom_bar(aes(y=value), fill = "dodgerblue4", stat="identity", size=0.5) + # Specify bar ts plot
    geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = 0, aes(color="red")) + # horizontal line @ y=0
    xlab("Period of Observation") + ylab("Millions of US Dollars ($)") + # label
    #scale_fill_manual(values = c("tomato", "forestgreen")) + #For conditional coloring
    theme(legend.position = "none") + #turn off the legends
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b", date_minor_breaks = "1 month") + #Add x-axis ticks
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.25))) + # Change axis label text size
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) # Remove x-axis label
```

[The negative area is omitted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzkIY.png)

Comment: Have you tried generating this plot outside shiny? Are the negative bars displayed then?

Answer (score 0):

Can this discussion help you ?
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/560